# Getting "Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance" but I'm not using a Queue

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I am trying to use a ProcessPoolExecutor, but I am getting the error "Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance", but I am not using a Queue (at least not explicitly). I can't find anything that explains what I am doing wrong.

Here is some code that demonstrates the issue (not my actual code):

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed

class WhyDoesntThisWork:

    def __init__(self):
        self.executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(4)

    def execute_something(self, starting_letter):
        futures = [self.executor.submit(self.something, starting_letter, d) for d in range(4)]
        letter = None
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            letter = future.result()
        print(letter)

    def something(self, letter, d):
        # do something pointless for the example
        for x in range(d):
            letter = chr(ord(letter) + 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WhyDoesntThisWork(). execute_something('A')
```

El Ruso has pointed out that making something() a staticmethod or classmethod makes the error go away. Unfortunately, my actual code needs to call other methods using self.

Comment: Actually you *are* using two queues! Explanation: all objects submitted to a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` are serialized. So when you submit the method `self.something` (which is an object that stores `self` in its `__self__` attribute, cf. [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/descriptor.html#id8)), `self` is serialized too, so it must be serializable. But because of its `self.executor` attribute, it is not, since a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` has an underlying call `multiprocessing.Queue` and result `multiprocessing.Queue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code for `something`

```
@staticmethod
def something(letter, d):
    # do something pointless for the example
    for x in range(d):
        letter = chr(ord(letter) + 1)
```

or refactor to:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed


class WhyDoesntThisWork:
    def something(self, letter, d):
        # do something pointless for the example
        for x in range(d):
            letter = chr(ord(letter) + 1)
        return letter


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(4)
    letter = 'A'
    obj = WhyDoesntThisWork()
    futures = [executor.submit(obj.something, letter, d) for d in range(4)]
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        print(future.result())
```

Comment: But in my real code that can't be static because it calls other methods on self.

Comment: `classmethod` can be used too.

Comment: So why does calling a regular instance method cause the error?

Comment: I still don't understand why the original code doesn't work, but I was able to refactor my code so that I could make all the methods that needed to be called classmethods. This solves my problem. Thank you!!

Comment: I don't know reasons of this behavior too

Answer (score 6):

Can be solved without using static approach.

When using process, each process runs in an independent memory space. That's unlike when using thread, when different threads are running under the same process, using the same memory space. Thus the error doesn't occur when you use 
`ThreadPoolExecutor` but occurs in `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

So when the function of the class instance is delivered into separate sub-processes, the multiprocessing mechanism pickles the function so that the function can be passed into the sub-process as an independent instance. And when the sub-process joined, the class is updated by the function instance delivered back as unpicked one.

To make it work, just add `__getstate__()` and `__setstate__()` functions to the class to guide the class how to pickle and unpickle the function. In pickling, the unnecessary fields can be excluded as shown in `del self_dict['executor']`.

```
import multiprocessing
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed


class GuessItWorksNow():

    def __init__(self):
        self.executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(4)

    def __getstate__(self):
        state = self.__dict__.copy()
        del state['executor']
        return state

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__.update(state)

    def something(self, letter, d):
        # do something pointless for the example
        p = multiprocessing.current_process()
        time.sleep(1)
        for x in range(d):
            letter = chr(ord(letter) + 1)
        return (f'[{p.pid}] ({p.name}) ({letter})')

    def execute_something(self, starting_letter):
        futures = [self.executor.submit(self.something, starting_letter, d) for d in range(10)]
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            print(future.result())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = GuessItWorksNow()
    obj.execute_something('A')
```