# Python Queue inheritance issues with multiple processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Queue
import schedule
import time

def checkBirthdays(accountQueue):
    print('[CheckBirthdays] Initated')
    acc = {
        'email': 'demo@test.com'
    }
    accountProcessing = [] if accountQueue.empty() else list(accountQueue.get())
    accountProcessing.append(acc)
    accountQueue.put(accountProcessing) # ****

def createSchedule(accountQueue):
    # similar to cron, executes at a certain time
    schedule.every().day.at("23:51").do(checkBirthdays, accountQueue)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        # check every 60 seconds
        time.sleep(60)

def main():
    # FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
    manager = Manager()
    accountQueue = manager.Queue()

    # RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
    # accountQueue = Queue()
    schedule = Process(target=createSchedule, args=(accountQueue,)).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Manager().Queue() gives this error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. I'm not certain while I get a FileNotFound error, it loads the pickle file fine with Queue()

Queue() gives this error `RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance` at `****` marks

```
[CheckBirthdays] Initated
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 827, in _callmethod
    conn = self._tls.connection
AttributeError: 'ForkAwareLocal' object has no attribute 'connection'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 313, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/tehpirate/Documents/Kelloggs/test.py", line 18, in createSchedule
    schedule.run_pending()
  File "/home/tehpirate/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 780, in run_pending
    default_scheduler.run_pending()
  File "/home/tehpirate/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 100, in run_pending
    self._run_job(job)
  File "/home/tehpirate/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 172, in _run_job
    ret = job.run()
  File "/home/tehpirate/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 661, in run
    ret = self.job_func()
  File "/home/tehpirate/Documents/Kelloggs/test.py", line 10, in checkBirthdays
    accountProcessing = [] if accountQueue.empty() else list(accountQueue.get())
  File "<string>", line 2, in empty
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 831, in _callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 818, in _connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 502, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 629, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Not reproducible.  Make a [mcve].  Get rid of code not needed to reproduce the issue and focus on the code causing the problem.  What is `acc` object?

Comment: Where imports? What is `schedule`, `IMAP`, etc? Please, copy-paste the sample to a new file as you've provided and edit until it actually runs **and** reproduces the question's problem. Then copy-paste back to the question.

Comment: For now I can come up at least with duplicate candidates: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47163820/5994041), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60959701/5994041), [rest](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Queue+objects+should+only+be+shared+between+processes+through+inheritance).

Comment: @PeterBadida I edited and added minimal running example

Comment: @MarkTolonen `acc` is a custom class object, I've edited above for clarification

Comment: Your master process shuts down as soon as it's done starting the worker. That breaks stuff. Why are you using multiprocessing at all?

Comment: This is a minimal execution script. There's more to it but I'm only focusing on the error right now. Everything in my project works fine, with other multiple processes. The master process does not shut down in my project. If I disable birthday check it'll run for days no issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only added [`Manager.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) (seconds adjusted, obviously) as shown in the documentation to keep the master running and the slaves active. If I remove that line `manager.join()`, it'll immediately drop to the error message you have.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Queue
import schedule
import time

def checkBirthdays(accountQueue):
    print('[CheckBirthdays] Initated')
    acc = {
        'email': 'demo@test.com'
    }
    accountProcessing = [] if accountQueue.empty() else list(accountQueue.get())
    accountProcessing.append(acc)
    accountQueue.put(accountProcessing) # ****

def createSchedule(accountQueue):
    # similar to cron, executes at a certain time
    schedule.every(1).seconds.do(checkBirthdays, accountQueue)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        # check every 60 seconds
        time.sleep(1)

def main():
    # FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
    manager = Manager()
    accountQueue = manager.Queue()

    # RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
    # accountQueue = Queue()
    schedule = Process(target=createSchedule, args=(accountQueue,)).start()
    manager.join()  # <--------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It's happening because there's an internal machinery that handles the inter-process communication via a Socket in this case. If a master or one of its slaves is killed, the communication tunnel shuts as well, thus it'll say there's no such "file" as in the end, socket is still a (kind of) file on Unix-based systems.

What `manager.join()` really does is that it checks if the master (your `manager`) can discard the slave processes because there's no use for them anymore (last program line executed, crash, etc) or whether to "reschedule" this action to the future and keep running.

Something like this, in a high-level code sketch:

```py
import time

while True:  # executed in the master process
    for slave in get_all_slaves():
        state = discard_if_posible(slave)
        # do stuff with the final state from the slave
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

To go more in-depth, `Manager._process` is [nothing more than a `Process` instance](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a1437170039dc2c07e6040d3a8ba8d91434b730d/Lib/multiprocessing/managers.py#L555) and here are the `join()`s:

- [master](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a1437170039dc2c07e6040d3a8ba8d91434b730d/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L142)
- [slave](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a1437170039dc2c07e6040d3a8ba8d91434b730d/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L378)

Finally, consider using context managers for the classes to prevent shutdown/cleanup issues to happen as well. There's a reason why there are `with`, `__enter__()` and `__exit__()`, especially in the multiprocessing codebase.

---

Edit: The code works just fine. Either you haven't provided a minimal working example reproducing your problem or you haven't fixed it by the proposed answer.

```
/tmp$ mkdir mpanswer && cd mpanswer
/tmp/mpanswer$ cat << EOF > main.py 
> from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Queue
> import schedule
> import time
> 
> def checkBirthdays(accountQueue):
>     print('[CheckBirthdays] Initated')
>     acc = {
>         'email': 'demo@test.com'
>     }
>     accountProcessing = [] if accountQueue.empty() else list(accountQueue.get())
>     accountProcessing.append(acc)
>     accountQueue.put(accountProcessing) # ****
> 
> def createSchedule(accountQueue):
>     # similar to cron, executes at a certain time
>     schedule.every(1).seconds.do(checkBirthdays, accountQueue)
>     while True:
>         schedule.run_pending()
>         # check every 60 seconds
>         time.sleep(1)
> 
> def main():
>     # FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>     manager = Manager()
>     accountQueue = manager.Queue()
> 
>     # RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
>     # accountQueue = Queue()
>     schedule = Process(target=createSchedule, args=(accountQueue,)).start()
>     manager.join()  # <--------------------------------
> 
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     main()
> EOF
/tmp/mpanswer$ cat << EOF > Dockerfile 
> FROM python:alpine
> COPY main.py main.py
> RUN pip install schedule
> CMD python main.py
> EOF
/tmp/mpanswer$ docker build --no-cache --tag mpanswer . && docker run --rm -it mpanswer
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/4 : FROM python:alpine
 ---> 03c59395ddea
Step 2/4 : COPY main.py main.py
 ---> 4ebcad402bf1
Step 3/4 : RUN pip install schedule
 ---> Running in 3b4dcc189d48
Collecting schedule
  Downloading schedule-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Installing collected packages: schedule
Successfully installed schedule-1.1.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.0; however, version 21.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Removing intermediate container 3b4dcc189d48
 ---> 039c1a333a5d
Step 4/4 : CMD python main.py
 ---> Running in 9dacf9084f28
Removing intermediate container 9dacf9084f28
 ---> de1391085794
Successfully built de1391085794
Successfully tagged mpanswer:latest
[CheckBirthdays] Initated
[CheckBirthdays] Initated
[CheckBirthdays] Initated
[CheckBirthdays] Initated
^C
/tmp/mpanswer$
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth insight! However I now get `RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance` at the same `***` mark

Comment: @TehPirate Check the edit.

Comment: I've solved the error. I was initiating a new Queue for the `acc` object, `acc.queue = Queue()` which was rendering the error. I've re-worked my account class logic and now it's resolved.